# Why does my phone say my photos are like 9Gb out of my phone yet I've deleted thousands of it and I still have no memory left?

Tags: iphone, icloud, storage

Is it because I have 40,000 pics in iCloud? But I still have 1 terabyte of storage. Can someone PLEASE explain to me how iCloud works. My phone will randomly gets rid of a whole photos albumn but then only a fraction of the pictures are left. Also I CANT SEE MY PHOTO ABUMS IN THE ICLOUD APP only online   Someone please help me. I would like to be able to download apps and have my music play without stopping because it "cannot download song". Thank you ☺️

Answer (score 1):

You've got some different questions here. The iCloud app isn't meant to show your photos; that's what the Photos app is for. When you delete photos, it doesn't actually delete them; it puts them in a folder called "Recently Deleted" where they are retained for 30 days before actually being deleted. You have to delete them again from that folder if you want to delete them before the 30 days are up.

To see what's using space on your phone, go into Settings / General / Storage & iCloud Usage / Manage Storage (the first one, under "STORAGE" not under "ICLOUD").